# Parsing Regular Expression in .net

Tags: regex

I need to Parse a string like `RANDOM(1)` and take a number `1` case insensitive. Now i use the following code:

```
string v = "RANDOM(156)";
v = v.ToUpper().Remove(v.Length - 1).Replace("RANDOM", "").Remove(0, 1);
return int.TryParse(v, out x);
```

I want to rework this in a regex way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex `RANDOM\(([\d]+?)\)`. In first group you will get whatever number occurs between round brackets.

Hope it helps.